# How to duplicate Jelly Bean "clear all notifications" animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to implement the same kind of animation that happens when clicking the "clear all" button in the notification bar:

> [image: normal clear all]

This is what I have now (for a `ListView`) but it's not working correctly. Because of timing/pauses, I think.

```java
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
animation.setDuration(300);

int count = mNotificationList.getCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    View view = mNotificationList.getChildAt(i);

    if (view != null)
        view.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

Anyone knows how to accomplish the animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve such an effect you should use a different `Animation` for each item, so you can easily set different starting offset via [`Animation.setStartOffset(long)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setStartOffset%28long%29) method.

Your code should look like this:

```
int count = mNotificationList.getCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    View view = mNotificationList.getChildAt(i);
    if (view != null) {
        // create an Animation for each item
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
            getActivity(),
            android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
        animation.setDuration(300);

        // ensure animation final state is "persistent"
        animation.setFillAfter(true);

        // calculate offset (bottom ones first, like in notification panel)
        animation.setStartOffset(100 * (count - 1 - i) );

        view.startAnimation(animation);
    }
}
```